# How to show a graph between to self picked dates in php

Tags: php, charts, google-visualization

So i have created a page where i can input something to my form fields and then insert it into my database with an attached date. I have then created a graph showing the input value.
The website is looking like this [image]

I want to be able to pick between to dates from the form field at the bottom to created an interval within the graf needs to contain all of the dates between.

My current code is the following:

```
<?php
  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost:8889","root","12345","recovery");
  $month = date('m');
  $day = date('d');
  $year = date('Y');

  $today = $year . '-' . $month . '-' . $day;
  ?>
<form class="" action="insert.php" method="post">
Training Intensity
<input type="number" placeholder="1-10" name="TI">
<br>
Training Duration
<input type="number" placeholder="in minutes" name="TD">
<br>
Date
<input type="date" class="form control" name="date" value="<?php echo $today; ?>">
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Date', 'RPE rating'],
          <?php
                  $sql = "SELECT * FROM rpe ORDER BY dot ASC;";
                  $fire = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                   while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fire)) {
                     echo"['".$result['dot']."',".$result['rpe']."],";
                   }

                  ?>
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Rate of Percieved Exertion Daily',
          hAxis: {title: 'Date',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
          vAxis: {minValue: 0}
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>

<form class="" action="" method="post">
  <input type="date" name="date1" name="Start date">
  <input type="date" name="date1" value=<?php echo $today; ?> name="Start date">
  <input type="submit" name="Chooseinterval" value="Choose interval">
</form>
```

With the insert.php page just inserting my values to my database
Im new to the google charts feature and would appreciate some help, thanks in advance

Comment: What issue(s) are you having? You have two start date fields and you `interval` field doesnt take a value.

Comment: i simply dont really know how to define an interval in google charts

Comment: I think you'd just modify the mysql return so the data is aggregated in whatever version you require. (e.g. day, month, year, decade, etc.)